# Grouping tabular data by multiple columns

Tags: perl

I have the data in this format

```
b1  1995    1
b1  2007    0.1
b2  1974    0.1
b2  1974    0.6
b2  1975    0.3
```

And, I want to sum values in column 3 based on similar values in both columns 1 and 2.

I have written a code where it sums up the value but I do not know how to print the groups values.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
my $file=shift;
open (DATA, $file);
my %score_by_year;

while ( my $line = <DATA> )
{
        my ($protein, $year, $score) = split /\s+/, $line;
        $score_by_year{$year} +=$score;
        print "$protein\t$year\t$score_by_year{$year}\n";
}
close DATA;
```

so my code gives output as:

```
b1  1995    1
b1  2007    0.1
b2  1974    0.1
b2  1974    0.7
b2  1975    0.3
```

whereas, the expected output is this:

```
b1  1995    1
b1  2007    0.1
b2  1974    0.7
b2  1975    0.3
```

Comment: Tip: Don't use global vars for file handles, especially not `DATA` (which already has meaning). Use lexical vars. /// Don't use 2-arg open. /// Check the result of `open` cause it's a frequent source of failure.  `open(my $fh, '<', $qfn) or die("Can't open \"$qfn\": $!\n");`

Comment: Tip: `split ' ', $line` almost always makes more sense than `split /\s+/, $line`. Though if your input is tab-separated like your output `split /\t/, $line` would be the appropriate solution here.

Comment: Heretical non-perl approach using the ever-useful [gnu datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/): `datamash groupby 1,2 sum 3 < input.tsv`. (If your real input isn't already sorted the way your sample is, add `-s`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the sequence, store it:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @sequence;
my %scores_by_year;

while (<DATA>) {
   my ($protein, $year, $score) = split;
   if (not exists $scores_by_year{$protein}{$year}) {
     push @sequence, [$protein, $year];
   }
   $scores_by_year{$protein}{$year} += $score;
}

for my $protein_year (@sequence) {
  my($protein, $year)= @$protein_year;
  print join("\t", $protein, $year, $scores_by_year{$protein}{$year}), "\n";
}
__DATA__
b1  1995    1
b1  2007    0.1
b2  1974    0.1
b2  1974    0.7
b2  1975    0.3
```